# batch file: for loop running twice

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I'm trying to write a batch which extracts a value of a parameter from an ini file. The problem is that this for loops iterates twice:

```
call:ini DW_LOADER_FeedsRootDir UDM_Folder
:ini
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%U in ('find "%~1=" DW_environmentConfig.ini') do (
 set %~2=%%U
)
```

the batch does not end after this line, and all the commands that follow it are also repeated twice.
I can't use a command like 'goto:eof' after the loop. 
Does anyone has an idea as to why this happens?

Answer (score 5):

When you use `CALL:INI` the batch calls your function, and when it ends, it returns to `CALL` command point, then it goes to `:ini` label again.

Try it:

```
call:ini DW_LOADER_FeedsRootDir UDM_Folder
goto:eof
:ini
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%U in ('find "%~1=" DW_environmentConfig.ini') do (set %~2=%%U)
```